# change the URL without changing the resource name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-resources

I'm building a website for a rabbit farmer (let's pretend).  This man keeps a close eye on his rabbits, and wants them all categorized.  So I built him a RabbitCategoriesController, and added this line to my routes.rb

```
resources :rabbit_categories
```

The URLs are showing up as `rabbit_categories`, `rabbit_categoriew/new`, etc.

What if I want the URLs to look like `rabits/categories` `rabits/categories/new` instead?  This is **not** a nested resource, I just want to change the way the URLs look.

Of course, if the resources were called "categories", I could do

```
namespace :rabbits do
  resources :categories
end
```

Is there any way I can write that, but tell it to use the RabbitCategoriesController instead of the Rabbits::CategoriesController?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

have you tried this, should work

```
resources :rabbit_categories, :path => "rabbits/categories"
```

See [Rails Routing from Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths) for more details.